# Trouble with @font-face in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I am trying to use a @font-face kit from fontsquirrel.com. I have pulled everything directly from the files they provide but when testing in IE9 using the developer tools I get the following results:

Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 standards - font renders correctly
Browser Mode: IE8, Document Mode: IE8 standards - font does not render
Browser Mode: IE7, Document Mode: IE7 standards - font does not render

The curious and infuriating thing is when I view the demo file from the @font-face kit it renders correctly in all three of the above situations. And like I said everything is copy/paste from the files provided.

The only difference I can think of is that I am using HTML5 Boilerplate.

Any thoughts would be appreciated greatly.

**In Response to the comments:**

Here is the font: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-neue

And the CSS I'm using:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "BebasNeueRegular";
src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
     url('BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('BebasNeue-webfont.svg#webfontfvFLBU0N') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the @font-face rule you are using? Thanks.

Comment: IIRC IE9 has an all new text rendering engine, which explains the difference.  You're saying the font is not used at all in the other versions?

Comment: We use the @font-face kit from FontSquirrel successfully in all browsers

Comment: @Beatriz: fontsquirrel's generator can only do so much.  Its success varies by source font.  Some fonts are oddly made, some are badly made.

Comment: @Jason: font-face rule would be useful, and the font name/font file/website if you can provide them.

Comment: @Jason: did you use the kit you can download from that page, where it says 'font-face Kit', then 'Download font-face Kit'?  This works fine for me in IE7 & 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason, your `font-face` code does not quite match what came in the kit I downloaded. Notice the fourth line (I marked with some commented exclaimations) is different than yours.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* !!! */
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: That fixed it. That's interesting, it's been a few weeks since I downloaded the kit. Maybe they have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: All you actually need, IIRC, is a '?' after the .eot, no format parameters, no woff, no svg, no extra eot.

Comment: Then it would not work for other browsers. He had issues with IE, but he wants it to work cross browser (that's why the other stuff is there). The only one that might be argued to be ditched is the .woff, but the .ttf is most other browsers, and .svg for iphone and ipad.